# NoClassDefFoundError after adding Opencsv jar to project

Tags: java, android, jar, opencsv

I've added the `open csv jar` to my project to enable data to be written out to file in csv format.

The jar file was added using the following steps:

```
1.Properties --> Add external jars --> opencsv-3.1.jar
2.Order & Eport tab --> tick, opencsv-3.1.jar
```

But when I run the project I get an error stating that one of the methods belonging to the opencsv jar cannot be found:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.opencsv.CSVWriter`

Does anyone know how to resolve this error or am I missing some step in adding the jar to the project?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [javadoc](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/) of API

CSVWriter is in au.com.bytecode.opencsv package

Comment: Do you mean I need to download a different jar file, as this method is not in my current jar? Also can you provide a link to the relevant download, thanks

Comment: Is it a specific jar file? The one I have downloaded is 3.1.

Comment: You can see in which package is class what you need in javadoc of library, with archiver (like winrar) by extracting jar or if you use IDE -you can see in reference libraries

Comment: Package of your API and package of imported APIs is not the same thing. com.opencsv is package in your app?

Comment: The package in my app is this jar file: `http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/` So I need to import a different jar for open csv? Do you know which version?

Answer (score 1):

As cross-listed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626457/noclassdeffounderror-com-opencsv-csvwriter/41538328#41538328), this was my solution to the problem:

I have been struggling with getting OpenCSV set up with Maven and eclipse for a while due to exactly the same error. Ultimately I abandoned OpenCSV and used [CSVParser instead](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html), which is available from the Apache Commons and works much more readily.

Update your POM with the dependency [listed here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.1), and the following will work out-of-the-box:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class importFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reader in = new FileReader( csvFileInput );
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser( in, CSVFormat.DEFAULT );
        List<CSVRecord> list = parser.getRecords();

        for( CSVRecord row : list )
            for( String entry : row )
                System.out.println( entry );
    }
}
```